# iOS UITableView with 10,000 record SQLLite DB

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

My iOS app populates an SQLlite database (using FMDB) from a web query. There is a UITableView to display this data. Since I started writing the app the size of this db has exploded to about 10,000 records.

My current design is to load the data in an array from the db and then use that in the UITableView. It works, and I have the alphabetized index on the right hand side of the screen for the user to quickly access the data.

The problem of course is it takes 15-20 seconds to load the array. I originally designed this to load every time the user hits the UITableView, but that means 15-20 seconds every time.

Is there a way to only load *some* of the data in the UITableView while keeping the search functionality and the index?

Can/should I load the array once and reuse it? I have tried but I can't seem to get that work.

As a last resort, I could switch to CoreData but I really don't want to switch horses in midstream.

UITableView implementation:

```
    #import "ContactViewController.h"
    #import "ContactDetailViewController.h"

    @interface ContactViewController ()
    @end

    @implementation ContactViewController {

      NSMutableArray *_contacts;
      UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
      BOOL isSearching;
    }

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
      if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==
          UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
      }
      [super awakeFromNib];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

      [super viewDidLoad];

      // Get array of employees and sections
      _contacts = [ContactsDatabase getContacts];
      self.sections = [ContactsDatabase getSections:_contacts];

      // Set up Search
      self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
      self.filteredContacts = [NSMutableArray array];
      searchController.delegate = self;
      searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
      isSearching = FALSE;

      // iPad
      // self.dtailViewController = (detailViewController
      // *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject]
      // topViewController];

      // Set the back bar button
      UIBarButtonItem *backButton =
          [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contacts"
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                          target:nil
                                          action:nil];
      self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    }

    #pragma mark - Table View
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      NSInteger tmpRows;
      if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        tmpRows = [self.filteredContacts count];
      } else {
        tmpRows = [[self.sections
            valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys]
                            sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                                @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
                            objectAtIndex:section]] count];
      }
      return tmpRows;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell =
          [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }

      if (isSearching) {
        contact *thisContact = [self.filteredContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisContact.cmpNme;
      } else {
        contact *thisContact = [[self.sections
            valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys]
                            sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                                @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
                            objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]
            objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisContact.cmpNme;
      }

      return cell;
    }

    #pragma mark - Table Sections
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      NSInteger tmpCount;
      if (isSearching) {
        tmpCount = 1;
      } else {
        tmpCount = [[self.sections allKeys] count];
      }
      return tmpCount;
    }

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

      NSString *tmpString;
      if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        tmpString = nil;
      } else {
        tmpString = [[[self.sections allKeys]
            sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
            objectAtIndex:section];
      }
      return tmpString;
    }

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showContactDetail"]) {

        contact *dtlContact;

        if (isSearching) {
          dtlContact = [self.filteredContacts
              objectAtIndex:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView
                                .indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        } else {
          dtlContact = [[self.sections
              valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys]
                              sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                                  @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
                              objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
                                                .section]]
              objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        }

        self.contactDetailViewController.detailItem = dtlContact;
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:dtlContact];
      }
    }

    #pragma mark - Right side bar alphabetical index
    - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

      NSArray *tmpTitle;
      if (isSearching) {
        tmpTitle = nil;
      } else {
        tmpTitle = [[self.sections allKeys]
            sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
      }
      return tmpTitle;
    }

    #pragma mark - Search methods
    - (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:
                (UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
      isSearching = TRUE;
      self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
      [self.tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles];
    }

    - (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:
                (UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
      isSearching = FALSE;
      self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
      [self.tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles];
    }

    - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
                                 scope:(NSString *)scope {

      [self.filteredContacts removeAllObjects];

      NSPredicate *predicate =
          [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cmpNme contains[c] %@", searchText];
      NSArray *tempArray = [_contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

      // Move to filtered array
      self.filteredContacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
      self.sections = [ContactsDatabase getSections:_contacts];
    }

    - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
        shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {

      isSearching = TRUE;
      [self
          filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                             .scopeButtonTitles
                                         objectAtIndex:
                                             self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 .selectedScopeButtonIndex]];
      return YES;
    }

    @end
```

getContacts methods

```
    + (NSMutableArray *)getContacts {

      id tmpDatabasePath = [(AppDelegate *)
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] databasePathContacts];
      NSMutableArray *tmpContacts;
      tmpContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:tmpDatabasePath];
      [db open];
      FMResultSet *results =
          [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER by cmpNme"];
      while ([results next]) {
        contact *thisContact = [contact new];
        thisContact.cmpNme = [results stringForColumn:@"cmpNme"];
        thisContact.fstNme = [results stringForColumn:@"fstNme"];
        thisContact.lstNme = [results stringForColumn:@"lstNme"];
        thisContact.cntTyp = [results stringForColumn:@"cnttyp"];
        NSString *tst = [results stringForColumn:@"phnNbr"];
        thisContact.phnNbr = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[tst intValue]];
        thisContact.adr1 = [results stringForColumn:@"adr1"];
        thisContact.adr2 = [results stringForColumn:@"adr2"];
        thisContact.cty = [results stringForColumn:@"cty"];
        thisContact.ste = [results stringForColumn:@"ste"];
        tst = [results stringForColumn:@"zip"];
        thisContact.zip = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[tst intValue]];
        thisContact.ema = [results stringForColumn:@"ema"];
        tst = [results stringForColumn:@"id"];
        thisContact.id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[tst intValue]];
        [tmpContacts addObject:thisContact];
      }
      [db close];
      return tmpCon
```

Comment: Just use pagination with offsets in requests to DB.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are likely to crash due to memory issues on a real device trying to load that much data at once into memory. This is not a trivial problem to solve. I solved this after a lot of work. I can load a table view from a sqlite table with tens of thousands of records. You need to implement all kinds of crazy caching algorithms so you only load visible records as the user scrolls. And you need a way to very quickly determine the number of sections and row counts per section without loading all of the details of each record.